# UITableView performance problems in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, realm

I'm creating a simple messenger app and using `uitableview` to display messages. I have created two XIB files for two types of cells i.e. incoming and outgoing. Also I have added constraints to each cell to make textViews to be not at full width of the screen (picture below)

[image]

The problem is, when i scroll table view up and down i see some jumps of content (i.e. bad performance). I made all views opaque, but it didn't help. As data storage i'm using `Realm`.io, to fetch messages from it. I get group_key, and list messages in this group.
Here's my code:

```
extension MessageChatViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     var count = 0
     if !groupKey.isEmpty {
         let messagesForGroupInRealm = realm.objects(Messages).filter("group_key = '\(groupKey)'")
         if messagesForGroupInRealm.count != 0 {
             count += messagesForGroupInRealm.count
         }
     }

     return count
 }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let messagesForGroupInRealm = messagesForCurrentChat.sorted("created_at", ascending: true)

     if messagesForGroupInRealm.count != 0 {
         if indexPath.row < messagesForGroupInRealm.count {
             let message = messagesForGroupInRealm[indexPath.row]
             if message.owner_key == gCredentials["account_key"] {
                 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OutgoingChatMessageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OutgoingChatMessageCell
                 cell.outgoingTextView.text = message.content
                 cell.outgoingTextView.font = UIFont(name: "NotoSans", size: 16)
                 return cell
             } else {
                 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IncomingChatMessageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! IncomingChatMessageCell
                 cell.incomingTextView.text = message.content
                 cell.incomingTextView.font = UIFont(name: "NotoSans", size: 16)
                 return cell
             }
         }
     }
    return UITableViewCell()
 }

}
```

I also use dynamic height of cells:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     ....
     tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "OutgoingChatMessageCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "OutgoingChatMessageCell")
     tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "IncomingChatMessageCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "IncomingChatMessageCell")

     ....
     tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
     tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
     ....
  }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   }
```

So is there any way to get best performance for tableView?  Maybe i need somehow cache something ?:) Or maybe i made some mistake... Thanks for any advices (for Obj-C also)!

Comment: The counterpart of using "estimatedRowHeight" is the small jumps while scrolling when the size of the cells are different.

So, if I were you, I would try to calculate the size of the cell for each cell, and use "heightForRowAtIndexpath" method.

Comment: Maybe Is it better to calculate each cell in "heightForRowAtIndexPath"?

Comment: Yes. Maybe you can calculate the height of the cell depending on the size of the message.

Comment: can it be because of testing via simulator? Try on real device who knows.

Comment: No, on simulator it actually works good, but on my 4s it works very bad, even on 5c I see some lag

Comment: messagesForCurrentChat.sorted("created_at", ascending: true)
Remove this code from cellForRowAtIndexPath and put in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

I seems like you are re-querying and sorting the entire dataset every time you draw a cell (or get a count). That would be a lot of unneeded overhead and could easily slow things down.

Why don't you make `messagesForGroupInRealm` a class member? Then you only have to do the query once (on init), and can then just keep accessing it directly from there.